# setDrawerListener and related activities nullPointException

Tags: android

My code throws a `NullPointException` on the following three lines

```
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle)
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START
```

Here is my full activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    NavigationView navigationView = null;
    Toolbar toolbar = null;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

I followed various answers to try to fix them none of them worked please help.

MainActivity.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Tried adding the onDrawerOpened and onDrawerClosed.
and also the FrameLayout in the app_bar_main also Reports Empty Tag

Comment: Post your `XML` and what line gives the error?

Answer (score 0):

try putting variables here and add method onDrawerOpened, onDrawerClosed

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


NavigationView navigationView = null;
Toolbar toolbar = null;
DrawerLayout drawer;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


   drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
   navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close){

 @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

     }
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();


    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: getActivity inside the onDrawerOpened and onDrawerClosed does not get resolved :/

Comment: I found inflating layers helps better in my situation. Thank You.